# Unnecessary line break with listings and prebreak

Tags: listings

A `lstlisting` environment with `prebreak` may break lines unnecessarily. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7
1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true,prebreak=\space...]
1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7
1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

With `breaklines=false`, the line with 57 characters fits within the text block, while the line with 59 characters causes an overfull `\hbox`. Therefore, I would like `lstlisting` to leave the 57-character line alone but break the 59-character line. However, with `breaklines=true`, both lines are broken.

Is it possible to automatically break a line only if it exceeds the margins *without* the `prebreak` tokens?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: No offense, but using `prebreak=\space...` is a really bad idea, if only because `listings` may introduce line breaks at places where the MATLAB syntax doesn't allow it (e.g. inside a string literal). That would make your MATLAB listings look incorrect.

Comment: I have few string literals or comments. I would rather fix them manually rather than breaking every line manually.

Comment: I am also curious why the behavior occurs. My understanding is that the TeX linebreaking algorithm is essentially hyphenating my code from the use of \discretionary in the listings package. Why would TeX invoke a discretionary when the line fits fine without it?

Comment: @BrianSutton String literals are just one example of many cases where `listings` may introduce syntactically incorrect line breaks. Also, the line breaking performed by `listings` has nothing to do with the line breaking normally performed by TeX.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer to your question, but a case against your approach; if you take heed of it, your problem will become irrelevant.

### Don't rely on `listings` to introduce syntactically correct line breaks

My understanding is that you're typesetting MATLAB listings and you want the line-continuation token (`...`) to be introduced wherever `listings`' line-breaking mechanism (`breaklines`) introduces a line break. That's a really bad idea, because, that way, `listings` may introduce line breaks (and `...`) at places where the MATLAB syntax doesn't allow it.

Consider the example below. The typeset listing shows `...` occurring inside the string literal. However, in MATLAB, a string literal must end on the same line it began, and any `...` occurring within it is treated as just part of the string, not as a line continuation. Therefore, the output (i.e. the typeset listing) is misleading and shows incorrect MATLAB syntax, even though the source written inside the `lstlisting` environment is syntactically correct. Surely, that's not what you want...

[image]

This example should be enough to convince you that you (and your readers) should understand any line break that `listings` introduces as a *typesetting convenience*, not as a syntactically correct line break in the language considered.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=Matlab,
  breaklines=true,
  prebreak=\space...,
  showstringspaces=false,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
disp('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper')
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

### An alternative approach

If what you want is mark occurences of line breaks introduced by `listings` but without compromising the syntactic validity of your listings, I recommend using line numbers as cues. See the example below. For any given line, you can easily tell whether `listings` introduces a line break on the preceding line or not, simply by checking whether the current line has a line number (on the left).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstset{style=Matlab-editor}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
disp('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper')
x = linspace(1,4,11) 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: for information, [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) is just a little package, built on top of `listings`, that is meant to typeset MATLAB code as nicely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=flexible]
1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7
1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]